# How do you prevent the Solidify modifier from hiding the verticies in Edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, solidify-modifier

[image]

I am going through the donut tutorial on Youtube. I was on part 4 but started having this weird issue with Solidify so I went back to part 3 and am still not sure what I am doing wrong.
Basically, the vertices are invisible if the Thickness and Offset parameters have the same sign like this:
[image]
You can kind of see the vertices hiding in the middle.

Here is where they are hiding:
[image]

Here is to show the problem is the same regardless what sign the offset is:
[image]

But if they have different signs then this happens:
[image]

Here is another perspective of the problem:
[image]

Things I have tried that did not work:

-Turning off proportional editing

-Selecting all vertices then flipping them with Alt+N

-Using a negative offset

-Changing the scaling

-Changing the modifier stack order

-Restarting the software

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, yes I just now added it and added a link to it at the top of my post.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem, it's working as expected, if you don't want to see the Solidify in Edit mode (?) then deactivate the Edit Mode option in the modifier (second square button on the top of the modifier)

Comment: It's working exactly as it should do. Set the offset to 1 and the thickness to 0.0015. As @moonboots has described Andrew turns off the modifier display at [1:05](https://youtu.be/R1isb0x4zYw?list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&t=65) in part 4 allowing you to see the vertices. The only thing that you haven't done in your blend file is drag the solidify modifier above the subdiv one but that won't affect the vertices.

Comment: Ok I found the problem was I have to Apply the modifier, then the vertices appear.

Comment: I went through this problem and realized that in the previous build, I had not applied the scale - follow the link with the moment he comments on the future problems of not doing this. [This part of the tutorial](https://youtu.be/imdYIdv8F4w?t=444)